# How would I create a unit test that ensures my Header appears on the page after it is loaded and has the correct text?

Tags: unit-testing, ecmascript-6, polymer

I'm brand new when it comes to unit testing and I'm trying to create a unit test which isolates my Header and appears on the page after it is loaded and has the correct text. More specifically, this code:

```
  static get template() {
    return `
      <style include="my-todo-style-element"></style>
      // This part right here.
      <h1 id="grocery-list">Grocery List</h1>
      <section>
        <todo-input></todo-input>
        <ul id="list-container">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[list]]">
            <todo-item text="[[item.text]]" checked="[[item.checked]]" index="[[index]]" on-remove="removeItem" on-toggle="toggleItem"></todo-item>
          </template>
        </ul>
      </section>
    `
  }
```

Since I'm brand new to unit testing, I currently have this typed out in the same JS file:

```
  fireEvent() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('grocery-list', {detail: 
'tested!'}))
  }
}
```

With this as my test file:

```
<script>
test('fires an event', function(done) {
  myEl.addEventListener('grocery-list', function(event) {
    assert.equal(event.detail, 'tested!');
    done();
  });
  myEl.fireEvent();
});
</script>
```

Comment: you definitly need to post some more code!